# Create a list from Table

Tags: vba, list, show

I managed to enter data to a database via a form;
actually works like a charm.

Now, what I need, is a lookup function (preferably not a form), with which I can search a table on another worksheet.

Let's say, I have an edit field or a cell, in which I enter a term which shall be looked for in a certain column on the table in another worksheet.
I would like to get a list of all entries which contain the word and the value from another cell (an ID).

Example:

Search term: Tom

Table:

```
Tim | 2
Tom | 3
Tommy | 5
```

The List should Show Tom and Tommy and their respective IDs,
but everything I tried didn't turn out as intended (mostly didn't work at all)...

Comment: Where is the code you have tried? One possibility is to have an input box which provides a parameter for a stored procedure (i.e. "Tim") via an Excel data connection. The result of the stored procedure run would then be displayed in Excel.However, there may be security issues if you don't have "execute" security level on the sp database.

Comment: well, i tried some snippets i found on the interweb.

Maybe i didnt express myself correctly.
the database is actually withing the document itself.
it's actually a file which is existing along an Archive.
giving Information about title, year and Location of each of the folders